# How to create a select for each row of table in ms sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach

Suppose I have three tables:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to select the `CODE` which `IS ACTIVE` (=1) from products table, the `LINE NUM` and `DOCUMENT ID`, that exist in table lines and is from document which is type KYT

for example the output should be something like:

[image]

Obviously it should start like

```
SELECT DOCUMENT ID
FROM [TABLE DOCUMENT]
WHERE TYPE='KYT'
```

And then for each row do something. I do not know how to accomplish this

Comment: You should put your table values in text format not in image.

Comment: You'll want to become familiar with the `join` statement

Comment: Welcome to SQL (or with more specifically T-SQL if you're using SQL Server). It seems that you're just starting out with the language, and so I suggest having a look at some online tutorials or guides on how to use SQL. What you're asking about here is, as @gbeaven said, a `JOIN`. There are several types of `JOIN`, such as `INNER`, and `FULL`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT OUTER`. These are one of the most basic parts of the language, so it'll be worth while learning what each of them do and when to use them.

Comment: I have not done this again with three tables and was not sure. I have done it for two only...

Comment: @F.Mysir If you can do it with two you can do it with 3 ... n tables assuming the tables are related and have joining relationships.

Comment: thank you everybody, I am in the learning process if I create the tables in text format will the downvotes be removed? :\

Comment: @F.Mysir probably not - the down voters here can be quite vicious

Comment: @F.Mysir A couple things to help when you ask a question, limit "images" that contain data. It's much easier for people to copy and paste your data in to a table and test ourselves - can't copy from an image though. Also, adding code that you have already tried helps us get an idea where you may be getting hung up - try to provide sample code of what you've already tried.

Comment: Alright I will keep this in mind for next time. Sounds right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the `JOIN` lines to join your 3 tables:

```
SELECT [PT].[CODE], [TL].[LINE NUM], [TD].[DOCUMENT ID]
FROM [TABLE DOCUMENT] as TD
JOIN [TABLE LINES]    as TL
    on TL.[DOCUMENT ID] = TD.[DOCUMENT ID]
JOIN [PRODUCTS TABLE] as PT
    on PT.[PRODUCTS ID] = TL.[PRODUCT ID]
WHERE TYPE='KYT' AND PT.ISACTIVE = 1
```

Comment: I edit my post, I added which is active also so in the `WHERE` statement I am using
`WHERE TYPE='KYT' AND ISACTIVE=1`

Comment: Only thing I want to add is that it showed `Ambiguous column name '[DOCUMENT ID]'` I Changed it to `TD.[DOCUMENT ID]` , and it worked :D

Comment: @F.Mysir Ah, right, ambiguous because [DOCUMENT ID] exists in more than one table. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a JOIN. Below is a join which selects all rows from all three tables. Play around with it.

JOINs are an essential MUST KNOW concept for Relation Database Management systems. They can be straight forward like this example, or can get pretty wild depending on what you need them to do. If youre going to continue working with SQL, you need to ge proficient with these.

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN lines L ON p.[Products ID]=L.[Product ID]
INNER JOIN document d ON L.[Document ID]=d.[Document ID]
```

I’ll help you dissect this so you have a better idea of whats going on.

```
FROM products p
```

The ‘p’ is called an alias. It’s a way to shorten table names you might end up having to write multiple times plus helps with readability. You can alias however you want but I suggest making it meaningful like my example of using p for Products and so on and so forth.

```
INNER JOIN lines L ON p.[Products ID]=L.[Product ID]
```

The ON clause is used to “tie tables” together. This is normally a foreign key relationship in the schema. The column you are joining “ON” is the same data element. A basic example would be exactly like this one – product ID is in both tables and that’s how we relate the data from both tables together.